# How to shrink navbar on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, fullpage.js

I'm using Fullpage.js in my website. And with Fullpage.js, script for shrinking navbar is not working. When I tried to run script without Fullpage.js it worked perfectly.

CSS for NavBar

```
#navbar {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #212F56;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding: 50px 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    top: 0;
}
```

Script for shrinking Nav Bar

```
<script>
    window.onscroll = function()
    {
        scrollFunction()
    };
    function scrollFunction() 
        {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 10 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 10)
            {
            document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "5px 10px";
            }
        else {
            document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "50px 10px";
                }
            }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @Simone Rossaini What about a codepen !! [link] https://codepen.io/dopesoul/pen/XWmBzMo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work, its a problem with the fullpage.js library, it also gives out an error code in the console:

"fullPage: Fullpage.js version 3 has changed its license to GPLv3 and it requires a `licenseKey` option. Read about it here:"
and
"fullPage: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#options."

Here is the working shrinking navbar on codepen: 
[codepen](https://codepen.io/learn-webdevyt/pen/oNjMyyQ)

I just removed your script tag

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.8/fullpage.min.js" integrity="sha256-caNcSA0LvOCX90PTuEbwl+V09xPMca13CJUasl+VCtk=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Comment: This is not an error, it is license information. Also removing  whole library is hardly solution to OP's problem. And even the OP said: "When I tried to run script without Fullpage.js it worked perfectly"

Comment: @philip i don't want to remove fullPage.js lib.